# A simple pendulum inside a big plane-parallel plate capacitor

Tags: python, python-3.x

The pendulum bob has a mass m and a positive electric charge q. The capacitor plates are parallel to the surface of the Earth. The electric field inside the capacitor is directed vertically up and its magnitude is modulated by the pendulum motion as E(t) = E_0*|sin(θ)(t)where qE_0/mg=<1 and θ is the angle between the pendulum and the vertical line. The initial conditions are θ(0) = pi/2 rad and dθ/dt = 0 rad/s.

Let L = 1.0m and g = 9.8 m/s^2

(a) First, taking  = 0, estimate at which initial angle θ(0) the numerically obtained period is equal to the period predicted by the formula T = 2pi*sqrt(L/g) with the accuracy better than 1%.

(b) Find and plot the dependence of the period of oscillations of this pendulum on the parameter .

(c) What will happen with the pendulum if  = 1?

So for a) this is what I did

```
#import
%pylab nbagg
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Solve for T first
#let the length L be equal to 1
L = 1
g=9.8
T = 2*np.pi*np.sqrt(g)
print(T)

#let delta = d
#if d = 0 then the ODE becomes

#Define the ODE

w_0 = np.sqrt(g/L)

def dy_dt(y,t):
  y1 = y
  y2 = -w_0**2*sin(y1)
  dydt = (y1,y2)
  return dydt

#Integration values and interval
t_0 = 0
t_f = T
nt = 10000
t = linspace(t_0, t_f, nt)
```

Now I'm not sure how I can proceed as I am trying to solve for dθ/dt but it's given that dθ/dt is just 0.

Comment: The notation `sin(θ)(t)` is a bit ambiguous.  Do you mean `Sin(θ(t))` (where `θ` is a function of `t`)?

Comment: Sorry, yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've looked this over a few times.  It seems like a pretty fun problem, but I don't think that StackOverflow is the correct place for help just yet.  I see that you're new to this site, so I'd like to encourage you to break this up into multiple questions and direct them to the appropriate groups.

Since your code is actually working at this point in time, StackOverflow isn't quite the right venue for this question.  I would recommend seeking help on the [physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) for any questions relating to the physics behind this problem (such as how to set up the system of differential equations you need), and the [computational science stack exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com) site for questions on how to solve the differential equations you get numerically.

If you have issues with getting the code itself to work when you are further along in the problem, StackOverflow is definitely the best place to ask for help.